# How to install window xp from ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp

**How to install window xp from ubuntu ?**

is there is any way to install window xp from ubuntu my cd room is dead and my pc is old can't boot from usb

Answer (score 0):

Short of installing it in a virtual machine, no.

Comment: mean can't install ?

Comment: @user1898400, correct.